# Gerando DOMPDF com cabeçalho, corpo e rodapé

Tags: php, dompdf

Gostaria de saber se é possível (e como) criar uma pagina com o cabeçalho e o rodapé e ficar apenas chamando o conteúdo do corpo que necessito.

Vou ter que gerar vários `pdf`, e em todas terá que manter o cabeçalho e o rodapé.